# Applying a permutation along one axis in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to permute "dimensions" along a single axis of a tensor?

Something akin to `tf.transpose`, but at the level of "dimensions" along an axis, instead of at the level of axes.

To permute them randomly (along the first axis), there it `tf.random.shuffle`, and to shift them, there is `tf.roll`. But I can't find a more general function that would apply any given permutation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tf.gather` can be used to that end. In fact, it is even more general, as the indices it takes as one of its inputs don't need to represent a permutation.